# how to remove ckeditors/ tinyhints styles with html/css/javascript

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, textarea

I don't like the syles that i use in ckeditors to display in my long list content, jxt want it o be a paragraph(p) text without the any other styles added to it from the ckeditor textarea text.
See an image of what am talking about.

[image]

I jxt want it to be plain like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issues by using JQuery unwrap() function, Here is the snippet code i used.

```
        $('.vall-txt-body strong').contents().unwrap();
        $('.vall-txt-body p').contents().unwrap();
        $('.vall-txt-body i').contents().unwrap();
        $('.vall-txt-body a').contents().unwrap();
        $('.vall-txt-body div').contents().unwrap();
        $('.vall-txt-body img').contents().unwrap();
```

by so doing i was now able to remove any tags i don't want from the text